# Multithreaded iteration over groups for Julia GroupedDataFrame

Tags: multithreading, julia, dataframes.jl

I have a `GroupedDataFrame` in Julia 1.4 (DataFrames 0.22.1). I want to iterate over the groups of rows to compute some statistics. Because there are many groups and the computations are slow, I want to do this multithreaded.

The code

```
grouped_rows = groupby(data, by_index)
for group in grouped_rows
    # do something with `group`
end
```

works, but

```
grouped_rows = groupby(data, by_index)
Threads.@threads for group in grouped_rows
    # do something with `group`
end
```

results in `MethodError: no method matching firstindex(::GroupedDataFrame{DataFrame})`. Is there a way to parallelize the iteration over groups of DataFrame rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have an `AbstractVector` for `Threads.@threads` to work.

Hence collect your `grouped_rows`

```
Threads.@threads for group in collect(SubDataFrame, grouped_rows)
    # do something with `group`
end
```

Comment: @korenmiklos FWIW you should update to v1.0. as you start julia with multiple threads, the grouped operations will be run in threads by default.

Comment: @FlorianOswald but I understand that operations for `DataFrames.jl` get parallelized, for your custom processing you still need to handle parallelism yourself. Or you meant something else?

Comment: oh no, that's exactly what I meant. What I am saying is that if `do something with group` is for example `combine`, then the new dataframes.jl will run on threads (I didn't know that until today!). otherwise, like you say!

Comment: Yes! lots of DataFrames in-built APIs got multi threaded parallelism very recently! which is very nice.